# Laravel dynamic relationships - access model attributes on eager load

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

I have an Eloquent relationship on my Laravel model which is dynamic - that is, the value of a particular database field determines which model will get loaded. I am able to load this relationship fine when I first instantiate the model instance and then reference the relation, but it does not work when I eager load that relationship.

Specifically, I have a `Product` model. That product might or might not be a parent to another product. If the `parent_id` of the Product is set to `0` then that product is considered a parent part (whether or not it has children). If the `parent_id` is set to a different product's id, then that product is a child. I need to be able to access `Product::with('parent')` and know that the `parent` relation will return with *either* itself (yes, duplicated data) or a different product if it is a child.

Here is my relationship so far:

```
public function parent()
{
    if ($this->parent_id > 0) {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'parent_id', 'id');
    } else {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'id', 'id');
    }
}
```

When I am eager loading, `$this->parent_id` is always undefined and therefore this relation will only ever return itself even if it actually is a parent product.

Is there any way to access a model's attributes *before* a relation is eager loaded? I thought about working in a separate query before I return the relation, but I realized that I don't have access to the product's id to even run that query.

If that is not possible, what are some other ways to address this type of problem? It does not appear that this could be solved through a traditional polymorphic relationship. I only have two possible ideas:

- Add some sort of constraint to the `belongsTo` relation where I dynamically determine a foreign key.
- Create my own custom relationship that uses a foreign key based on a different database field.

I honestly have no idea how I would implement either of those. Am I going about this the right way? Is there something I am overlooking?

---

After thinking this over more, I think the simplest way to put the question is: **is there any way to dynamically select a foreign key for a relationship inside the relation itself at runtime**? My use cases don't allow for me to use eager loading constraints when I call the relation - the constraints need to apply to the relation itself.

Comment: Why not put the product's own id in the field if it isn't a parent'?

Comment: If I were starting from scratch I think I'd do that, but unfortunately I am creating a Laravel API service for a huge legacy codebase/database. If I modified how that field worked, it would break a buuuunch of code elsewhere. I've considered adding a new field that does that, but I would have to add a ton of legacy code in every place a product can be entered in the legacy site - a true nightmare project.

Comment: I was hoping for some way to be able to accomplish this using Laravel. If every alternative turns out to be impossible I will ping you and have you answer this so that at least your answer might help others trying to do the same thing - even though it would not help me. I'm going to give this question a little more time before giving up though.

Comment: Funny you should mention that, currently working on a similar project. I'll give it some more thought. Laravel's relationships are a little less robust than I hoped they would be.

Comment: Maybe try to handle it with Morph relationships?

Comment: @Froxz I mention it in my post, but I don't think there's any way that I could use polymorphic relationships for this type of thing (I use them a bunch elsewhere). That's because my relationship is not loading different *types* of models - it is loading different *instances* of models. I am relating a Product model with another Product model; I just need to know *which* product model to relate it to based off of another field. I really feel like there must be some way to modify my `belongsTo` object to check for that field, even if I have to use some raw SQL or something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of the way eager loading works, there isn't anything you can really do to the SQL being run to get done what you're looking for.

When you do `Product::with('parent')->get()`, it runs two queries.

First, it runs the query to get all the products:

```
select * from `products`
```

Next, it runs a query to get the eager loaded parents:

```
select * from `products` where `products`.`id` in (?, ?, ?)
```

The number of parameters (`?`) corresponds to the number of results from the first query. Once the second set of models has been retrieved, the `match()` function is used to relate the objects to each other.

In order to do what you want, you're going to have to create a new relationship and override the `match()` method. This will handle the eager loading aspect. Additionally, you'll need to override the `addConstraints` method to handle the lazy loading aspect.

First, create a custom relationship class:

```
class CustomBelongsTo extends BelongsTo
{
    // Override the addConstraints method for the lazy loaded relationship.
    // If the foreign key of the model is 0, change the foreign key to the
    // model's own key, so it will load itself as the related model.

    /**
     * Set the base constraints on the relation query.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function addConstraints()
    {
        if (static::$constraints) {
            // For belongs to relationships, which are essentially the inverse of has one
            // or has many relationships, we need to actually query on the primary key
            // of the related models matching on the foreign key that's on a parent.
            $table = $this->related->getTable();

            $key = $this->parent->{$this->foreignKey} == 0 ? $this->otherKey : $this->foreignKey;

            $this->query->where($table.'.'.$this->otherKey, '=', $this->parent->{$key});
        }
    }

    // Override the match method for the eager loaded relationship.
    // Most of this is copied from the original method. The custom
    // logic is in the elseif.

    /**
     * Match the eagerly loaded results to their parents.
     *
     * @param  array   $models
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection  $results
     * @param  string  $relation
     * @return array
     */
    public function match(array $models, Collection $results, $relation)
    {
        $foreign = $this->foreignKey;

        $other = $this->otherKey;

        // First we will get to build a dictionary of the child models by their primary
        // key of the relationship, then we can easily match the children back onto
        // the parents using that dictionary and the primary key of the children.
        $dictionary = [];

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $dictionary[$result->getAttribute($other)] = $result;
        }

        // Once we have the dictionary constructed, we can loop through all the parents
        // and match back onto their children using these keys of the dictionary and
        // the primary key of the children to map them onto the correct instances.
        foreach ($models as $model) {
            if (isset($dictionary[$model->$foreign])) {
                $model->setRelation($relation, $dictionary[$model->$foreign]);
            }
            // If the foreign key is 0, set the relation to a copy of the model
            elseif($model->$foreign == 0) {
                // Make a copy of the model.
                // You don't want recursion in your relationships.
                $copy = clone $model;

                // Empty out any existing relationships on the copy to avoid
                // any accidental recursion there.
                $copy->setRelations([]);

                // Set the relation on the model to the copy of itself.
                $model->setRelation($relation, $copy);
            }
        }

        return $models;
    }
}
```

Once you've created your custom relationship class, you need to update your model to use this custom relationship. Create a new method on your model that will use your new `CustomBelongsTo` relationship, and update your `parent()` relationship method to use this new method, instead of the base `belongsTo()` method.

```
class Product extends Model
{

    // Update the parent() relationship to use the custom belongsto relationship
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->customBelongsTo('App\Product', 'parent_id', 'id');
    }

    // Add the method to create the CustomBelongsTo relationship. This is
    // basically a copy of the base belongsTo method, but it returns
    // a new CustomBelongsTo relationship instead of the original BelongsTo relationship
    public function customBelongsTo($related, $foreignKey = null, $otherKey = null, $relation = null)
    {
        // If no relation name was given, we will use this debug backtrace to extract
        // the calling method's name and use that as the relationship name as most
        // of the time this will be what we desire to use for the relationships.
        if (is_null($relation)) {
            list($current, $caller) = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 2);

            $relation = $caller['function'];
        }

        // If no foreign key was supplied, we can use a backtrace to guess the proper
        // foreign key name by using the name of the relationship function, which
        // when combined with an "_id" should conventionally match the columns.
        if (is_null($foreignKey)) {
            $foreignKey = Str::snake($relation).'_id';
        }

        $instance = new $related;

        // Once we have the foreign key names, we'll just create a new Eloquent query
        // for the related models and returns the relationship instance which will
        // actually be responsible for retrieving and hydrating every relations.
        $query = $instance->newQuery();

        $otherKey = $otherKey ?: $instance->getKeyName();

        return new CustomBelongsTo($query, $this, $foreignKey, $otherKey, $relation);
    }
}
```

Fair warning, none of this has been tested.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I've never had much luck building my own relations before, but this does exactly what I need! However, I want to point out that in a specific use case this will not work: if you are using this in a nested `whereHas` query, i.e. `Product::whereHas('parent.location', function ($q) { //something })->find(1234)`. However, I think that has more to do with a shortcoming of the fact this builds subqueries on itself with other fields needed as a primary key and not this relation itself (if that makes sense). Just wanted to add it here in case someone else need it. Thank you!

Comment: @AndyNoelker Laravel has had an issue with `has` and `whereHas` on self relationships. I actually recently submitted PRs for 5.1 and 5.2 that were merged in that fix this issue. If you're on 5.1, version 5.1.30 was just tagged today about 40 minutes ago that has the fix. If you're on 5.2, version 5.2.15 was tagged 5 days ago that has the fix. If you need this `whereHas` functionality, you'll need to composer update Laravel.

Comment: @AndyNoelker If you care about the gory details, you can check out [PR #12146](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/12146).

Comment: You are a legend! Yep that update completely fixed the `whereHas` problem too!

Comment: Heeey so I probably should have done a little more testing before closing this issue. I focused so much on eager loading that I didn't bother to check that instantiating a product first and then calling `$product->parent` still worked. Turns out it does not for any product with `0` as a parent id. Did some testing and it looks like `match()` is only called when eager loading, not when accessing a relation like a property. Any thoughts on how this could be modified to accommodate for that?

Comment: So I added an edit to your answer with the fix. This relation also needed to override `addConstraints` to check for when the relation is being referenced like a property. It appears to be working now for me on all fronts (eager loading and property access) with this relation. Once again, thank you so much for all of your effort!

Comment: Well my edit was rejected, I guess because I added content and didn't just do a grammatical fix? SO has weird rules. Anyway, in case someone needs to know the *full* fix, you should pasted in the `addConstraints` function from `BelongsTo`, add this line `$key = $this->parent->{$this->foreignKey} == 0 ? $this->otherKey : $this->foreignKey;` and then on the line below it, have it go off the `$key` variable instead of the foreign key, like this `$this->parent->{$key}`

Comment: @AndyNoelker I did the same thing, focused on the eager loading and forgot about the lazy loading. I'm glad you got it figured out. I updated the answer with the relevant information. Reviewers on SO will generally reject edits to posted code. FYI, if you run into any issues with overriding the `addConstraints()` method, you could try overriding the `getResults()` method instead. But, I think you're good with the current code.

Comment: Thanks for updating and for the info!